# Грузятся ли в .NET одни и те же DLL в разные процессы или совместно используются?

Tags: .net, ос

Тоненбаум в книге "Операционные системы" пишет, что ОС отслеживает DLL, которые используются совместно разными процессами и не грузит в память N одних и тех же DLL.

Справедливо ли это для .NET?

Вроде, Рихтер писал, что для доменов приложения mscorlib общая, а все остальные DLL грузятся повторно.

Answer (score 1):

Обычные managed dll не разделяются между процессами, и загружаются в кажджый процесс заново, и каждый раз заново проходят через процедуру генерации нативного кода из IL. Сгенерированный машинный код также хранится в private памяти процесса, и не разделяется между приложениями.

Если у вас много экземпляров приложения, и накладные расходы на повторную загрузку dll становятся проблемой - пройдитесь по сборкам [утилитой ngen](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator#Memory). Нативные сборки на выходе ngen - это обычные Windows PE dll, они вполне шарятся между процессами.

Инсталлятор фреймворка запускает ngen при установке и самого фреймворка, и обновлений, выглядит это примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что скорее всего для всех стандартных сборок фреймворка у вас есть локальные native images, и они разделяются между процессами даже без ручного запуска ngen.